# Convert a list java.awt.geom.Point2D to a java.awt.geom.Area

Tags: java, awt

I have a set of points that i want to turn into a closed polygon in Java.  I'm currently trying to use java.awt.geom.Point2D and java.awt.geom.Area but can't figure out how to turn a group of the points into an Area.

I think I can define a set of Line2Ds based on the points and then add those to the Areas, but that's a lot of work and I'm lazy.  So is there an easier way to go.

The problem is I have a list of lat/lon coordinates and want to build up an area that I can use for hit testing.

Non-core Java libraries are a possibility as well.

Update, I looked at using java.awt.Polygon but it only supports ints and I'm operating with doubles for the coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4077518

Hear that, "customer"? You should be using GeneralPath, even though the absence of Polygon2D since the late 1990s is an obvious monster-truck-sized hole in the API.

Comment: Notice there is a Polygon2D implementation floating around which originally came from the Berkeley UI lab:

http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=5&url=http%3A%2F%2Fptolemy.eecs.berkeley.edu%2F~ptII%2FptolemyII%2FptIIlatest%2FptII%2Fdiva%2Futil%2Fjava2d%2FPolygon2D.java&ei=BNSeSqr3O4y4M7eMmIwC&usg=AFQjCNErxCV1f6zlpi60FEqPkgG1rAfx5A&sig2=eWfBVNHxVQzY1eJ3DZvC1Q

Comment: better link: http://ptolemy.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ptII/ptolemyII/ptIIlatest/ptII/diva/util/java2d/

Comment: `GeneralPath` is a legacy class by now. See [this question and answers for some alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11465330/935676). We can celebrate the 20th anniversary of this bug in September ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you are actually working with Geodetic lat/lon values, you can actually use [OpenMap](http://openmap.bbn.com/) to do some of this work.  I just spent some time using the [Geo class](http://openmap.bbn.com/doc/api/com/bbn/openmap/geo/Geo.html) in that API to bounce an object around an area defined by a polygon of lat/lon points.  There are [intersection calls](http://openmap.bbn.com/doc/api/com/bbn/openmap/geo/Intersection.html#getIntersectionGeo(float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float)) and everything and all of the math is done spherically so that the points are more correct as far as projections go.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest (and laziest) thing to do is to create a bounding box for the points from the maximum and minimum of the X, Y ordinate values.

If you need a closer fit then rather than devise your own algorithm, this might be a good place to start: