# Polygons with Double Coordinates

Tags: java, double, polygon

I have some questions about Polygons with points of Double type...
What I have  to do, is given points, create the polygon, and then, test if 1 concrete point is inside the polygon or not.

so I kwnow that in Java there's a class, called Polygon, and is used like that: (triangle)

```
int valoresX[] = { 100, 150, 200 };
int valoresY[] = { 100, 200, 100 };
int n = valoresX.length;
Polygon city= new Polygon(valoresX,valoresY,n);
```

But my "polygons" has to be of "Double" type, not "int" (easy example)

```
Double valoresX[] = { 1000.10, 150.10, 200.10 };
Double valoresY[] = { 100.10, 200.10, 100.10 };
```

In my project i dont really need to paint it on an applet or similar, I just need to calculate if the point is inside or not.

So my question is:

Is any way to do polygons with double coordenates , that allow to calcultate if the point(double) is inside the polygon or not?

Thanks for all!!!

Shudy

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can do this with [Path2D.Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.Double.html):

```
Path2D path = new Path2D.Double();

path.moveTo(valoresX[0], valoresY[0]);
for(int i = 1; i < valoresX.length; ++i) {
   path.lineTo(valoresX[i], valoresY[i]);
}
path.closePath();
```

See also this question:

[Implementing Polygon2D in Java 2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465330/implementing-polygon2d-in-java-2d)

Comment: First of all, thanks for all, and the fast answer!
I'mg gonna try it, and see if it works to my project ;)

Thanks! Shudy