# Create java.awt.geom.Area from points

Tags: java, geometry, awt, 2d, shapes

I am trying to create a java.awt.geom.Area (or any object that uses the Shape interface) to describe a set of points that create a complex shape. Here is an example:

[image: Yellow Blobs]

I am trying to create an Area object (or many Area objects) to describe the yellow area. I have an easy way of obtaining the coordinates of the yellow pixels, but I don't know how to create an Area object (or multiple Area objects) that contains all the yellow points.

This stackoverflow question seems very relevant [Create closed polygon from boundary points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326068/create-closed-polygon-from-boundary-points)) but is using Matlab. I think someone else asked a very similar question here ([Convert a list java.awt.geom.Point2D to a java.awt.geom.Area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369313/convert-a-list-java-awt-geom-point2d-to-a-java-awt-geom-area)) but the links provided in the answers are dead.

Answer (score 3):

E.G.

[image: Yellow Blob Outline]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.*;

/* See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/7052422/418556 */
class ImageOutline {

    public static Area getOutline(
        BufferedImage image, Color color, boolean include, int tolerance) {

        Area area = new Area();
        for (int x=0; x<image.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y=0; y<image.getHeight(); y++) {
                Color pixel = new Color(image.getRGB(x,y));
                if (include) {
                    if (isIncluded(color, pixel, tolerance)) {
                        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x,y,1,1);
                        area.add(new Area(r));
                    }
                } else {
                    if (!isIncluded(color, pixel, tolerance)) {
                        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x,y,1,1);
                        area.add(new Area(r));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return area;
    }

    public static boolean isIncluded(
        Color target, Color pixel, int tolerance) {

        int rT = target.getRed();
        int gT = target.getGreen();
        int bT = target.getBlue();
        int rP = pixel.getRed();
        int gP = pixel.getGreen();
        int bP = pixel.getBlue();
        return(
            (rP-tolerance<=rT) && (rT<=rP+tolerance) &&
            (gP-tolerance<=gT) && (gT<=gP+tolerance) &&
            (bP-tolerance<=bT) && (bT<=bP+tolerance) );
    }

    public static BufferedImage drawOutline(int w, int h, Area area) {

        final BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(
            w,
            h,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g = result.createGraphics();

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0,0,w,h);

        g.setClip(area);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(0,0,w,h);

        g.setClip(null);
        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.draw(area);

        return result;
    }

    public static BufferedImage createAndWrite(
        BufferedImage image,
        Color color,
        boolean include,
        int tolerance,
        String name)
        throws Exception {

        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();

        System.out.println("Get Area: " + new Date() + " - " + name);
        Area area = getOutline(image, color, include, tolerance);
        System.out.println("Got Area: " + new Date() + " - " + name);

        final BufferedImage result = drawOutline(w,h,area);
        displayAndWriteImage(result, name);

        return result;
    }

    public static void displayAndWriteImage(
        BufferedImage image, String fileName) throws Exception {

        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(fileName));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGBuT.png");
        final BufferedImage outline = ImageIO.read(url);
        displayAndWriteImage(outline, "motorcycle-01.png");
        createAndWrite(
            outline, Color.white, false, 60, "YellowBlobOutline.png");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a [GeneralPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/GeneralPath.html) or a [Path2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.html), both of which implement `Shape`. [This tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/arbitrary.html) explains how to use `GeneralPath`, which is very similar to `Path2D`. The `Shape` can then be used to create the `Area`.